# Unity il2cpp build LLVM error out of memory

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

Android studio build unity il2cpp project export such error, I change android studio -Xmx to 4g, but it does nothing help. Any idea?

> Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask
> WARNING: NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please delete ndk.dir from local.properties and set android.ndkVersion to [21.3.6528147] in all native modules in the project. https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/ndk-dir
> NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please delete ndk.dir from local.properties and set android.ndkVersion to [21.3.6528147] in all native modules in the project. https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/ndk-dir
> D:\CodeHub\MotionCaptureDemo\androidBuild\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\il2cpp.exe --compile-cpp --platform=Android --architecture=armv7 --outputpath=D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libil2cpp.so --libil2cpp-static --baselib-directory=D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/armeabi-v7a --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --configuration=Release --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_conv.traceevents --print-command-line --generatedcppdir=D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput --cachedirectory=D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache --tool-chain-path=D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147
> Starting: D:\CodeHub\MotionCaptureDemo\androidBuild\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\bee_backend\win-x64\bee_backend.exe --profile="D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --stdin-canary --dagfile="D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/bee.dag" --continue-on-failure FinalProgram
> WorkingDir: D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate
> ExitCode: 4 Duration: 0s26ms
> ExitCode: 0 Duration: 0s0ms
> Starting: D:\CodeHub\MotionCaptureDemo\androidBuild\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\bee_backend\win-x64\bee_backend.exe --profile="D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/backend_profiler1.traceevents" --stdin-canary --dagfile="D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/bee.dag" --continue-on-failure --dagfilejson="D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/bee.dag.json" FinalProgram
> WorkingDir: D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate
> NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please delete ndk.dir from local.properties and set android.ndkVersion to [21.3.6528147] in all native modules in the project. https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/ndk-dir

ExitCode: 3 Duration: 9m:59s
Build failed with 434 successful nodes and 1 failed ones
Annotation: C_Android_arm32 iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.o
Cmdline: "D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++" -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-fp16 -marm -D__ARM_ARCH_7__ -D__ARM_ARCH_7A__ -D__ANDROID_API__=22 -DANDROID -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -no-canonical-prefixes -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -fomit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -fvisibility=hidden -fexceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2 -fPIC -fno-strict-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -DBASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib -DIL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP -DIL2CPP_ENABLE_WRITE_BARRIERS=1 -DIL2CPP_INCREMENTAL_TIME_SLICE=3 -DHAVE_BDWGC_GC -DNDEBUG -I"." -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp/pch" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Include" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Platforms/Android/Include" -o "iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.o" -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -target armv7a-linux-androideabi22 -fstrict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -c -x c++ "D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp.cpp"
ExitCode: 1
Stdout:
**LLVM ERROR: out of memory**
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin\clang++.exe -cc1 -triple armv7-unknown-linux-android22 -emit-obj -mnoexecstack -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name Assembly-CSharp.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -target-feature +soft-float-abi -target-feature +fpregs -target-feature +vfp2 -target-feature +vfp2d16 -target-feature +vfp2d16sp -target-feature +vfp2sp -target-feature +vfp3 -target-feature +vfp3d16 -target-feature +vfp3d16sp -target-feature +vfp3sp -target-feature +fp16 -target-feature -vfp4 -target-feature -vfp4d16 -target-feature -vfp4d16sp -target-feature -vfp4sp -target-feature -fp-armv8 -target-feature -fp-armv8d16 -target-feature -fp-armv8d16sp -target-feature -fp-armv8sp -target-feature -fullfp16 -target-feature +fp64 -target-feature +d32 -target-feature +neon -target-feature -crypto -target-feature -fp16fml -target-abi aapcs-linux -mfloat-abi soft -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -coverage-notes-file D:\CodeHub\MotionCaptureDemo\androidBuild\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release\il2cpp_cache\buildstate\iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.gcno -resource-dir D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\9.0.8 -D **ARM_ARCH_7** -D **ARM_ARCH_7A** -D **ANDROID_API**=22 -D ANDROID -D HAVE_INTTYPES_H -D BASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib -D IL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED -D RUNTIME_IL2CPP -D IL2CPP_ENABLE_WRITE_BARRIERS=1 -D IL2CPP_INCREMENTAL_TIME_SLICE=3 -D HAVE_BDWGC_GC -D NDEBUG -I . -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp/pch -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Include -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Platforms/Android/Include -internal-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/local/include -internal-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\9.0.8\include -internal-externc-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -internal-externc-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/include -internal-externc-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include -O2 -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir D:\CodeHub\MotionCaptureDemo\androidBuild\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release\il2cpp_cache\buildstate -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility hidden -fwrapv -stack-protector 1 -fno-rtti -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-format msvc -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.o -x c++ D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp.cpp

1. parser at end of file
2. Code generation
3. Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp.cpp'.
4. Running pass 'Live DEBUG_VALUE analysis' on function '@Logo__cctor_m0B2A9E20017B45013046D090962CA14AA0DEB853'
   #0 0x00007ff649b9fca6 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x4efca6)
   #1 0x00007ffc3eeb1881 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll+0x71881)
   #2 0x00007ffc3eeb2851 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll+0x72851)
   #3 0x00007ff649b65824 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x4b5824)
   #4 0x00007ff6496c701b (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1701b)
   #5 0x00007ff649cfd1d1 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x64d1d1)
   #6 0x00007ff649d046f3 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6546f3)
   #7 0x00007ff649d048b6 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6548b6)
   #8 0x00007ff64ac10e8a (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1560e8a)
   #9 0x00007ff649d9a8c2 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6ea8c2)
   #10 0x00007ff6498b303b (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x20303b)
   #11 0x00007ff6498b3383 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x203383)
   #12 0x00007ff6498b39d5 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x2039d5)
   #13 0x00007ff64a6ad5ff (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0xffd5ff)
   #14 0x00007ff64a9c82e2 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x13182e2)
   #15 0x00007ff64b8f13f3 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x22413f3)
   #16 0x00007ff64a934a60 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1284a60)
   #17 0x00007ff649c6eb7f (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x5beb7f)
   #18 0x00007ff649cba8f6 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x60a8f6)
   #19 0x00007ff6496b6576 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6576)
   #20 0x00007ff6496b43fa (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x43fa)
   #21 0x00007ff6496b1395 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1395)
   #22 0x00007ff6496b14c8 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x14c8)
   #23 0x00007ffc402b7034 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x17034)
   #24 0x00007ffc410a2651 (C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x52651)
   clang++: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
   Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
   Target: armv7a-unknown-linux-android22
   Thread model: posix
   InstalledDir: D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin
   clang++: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
   clang++: note: diagnostic msg:

---

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\Z00430~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Assembly-CSharp-f3eb5e.cpp
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\Z00430~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Assembly-CSharp-f3eb5e.sh
clang++: note: diagnostic msg:

---

Error: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 434 successful nodes and 1 failed ones
Annotation: C_Android_arm32 iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.o
Cmdline: "D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++" -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-fp16 -marm -D__ARM_ARCH_7__ -D__ARM_ARCH_7A__ -D__ANDROID_API__=22 -DANDROID -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -no-canonical-prefixes -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -fomit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -fvisibility=hidden -fexceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2 -fPIC -fno-strict-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -DBASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib -DIL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP -DIL2CPP_ENABLE_WRITE_BARRIERS=1 -DIL2CPP_INCREMENTAL_TIME_SLICE=3 -DHAVE_BDWGC_GC -DNDEBUG -I"." -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp/pch" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Include" -I"D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Platforms/Android/Include" -o "iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.o" -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -target armv7a-linux-androideabi22 -fstrict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -c -x c++ "D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp.cpp"
ExitCode: 1
Stdout:
LLVM ERROR: out of memory
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin\clang++.exe -cc1 -triple armv7-unknown-linux-android22 -emit-obj -mnoexecstack -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name Assembly-CSharp.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -target-feature +soft-float-abi -target-feature +fpregs -target-feature +vfp2 -target-feature +vfp2d16 -target-feature +vfp2d16sp -target-feature +vfp2sp -target-feature +vfp3 -target-feature +vfp3d16 -target-feature +vfp3d16sp -target-feature +vfp3sp -target-feature +fp16 -target-feature -vfp4 -target-feature -vfp4d16 -target-feature -vfp4d16sp -target-feature -vfp4sp -target-feature -fp-armv8 -target-feature -fp-armv8d16 -target-feature -fp-armv8d16sp -target-feature -fp-armv8sp -target-feature -fullfp16 -target-feature +fp64 -target-feature +d32 -target-feature +neon -target-feature -crypto -target-feature -fp16fml -target-abi aapcs-linux -mfloat-abi soft -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -coverage-notes-file D:\CodeHub\MotionCaptureDemo\androidBuild\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release\il2cpp_cache\buildstate\iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.gcno -resource-dir D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\9.0.8 -D **ARM_ARCH_7** -D **ARM_ARCH_7A** -D **ANDROID_API**=22 -D ANDROID -D HAVE_INTTYPES_H -D BASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib -D IL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED -D RUNTIME_IL2CPP -D IL2CPP_ENABLE_WRITE_BARRIERS=1 -D IL2CPP_INCREMENTAL_TIME_SLICE=3 -D HAVE_BDWGC_GC -D NDEBUG -I . -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp/pch -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Include -I D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Platforms/Android/Include -internal-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/local/include -internal-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\9.0.8\include -internal-externc-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -internal-externc-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/include -internal-externc-isystem D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include -O2 -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir D:\CodeHub\MotionCaptureDemo\androidBuild\unityLibrary\build\il2cpp_armeabi-v7a_Release\il2cpp_cache\buildstate -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fvisibility hidden -fwrapv -stack-protector 1 -fno-rtti -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-format msvc -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o iz17/qd5o_bly-CSharp.o -x c++ D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp.cpp

1. parser at end of file
2. Code generation
3. Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'D:/CodeHub/MotionCaptureDemo/androidBuild/unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp.cpp'.
4. Running pass 'Live DEBUG_VALUE analysis' on function '@Logo__cctor_m0B2A9E20017B45013046D090962CA14AA0DEB853'
   #0 0x00007ff649b9fca6 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x4efca6)
   #1 0x00007ffc3eeb1881 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll+0x71881)
   #2 0x00007ffc3eeb2851 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll+0x72851)
   #3 0x00007ff649b65824 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x4b5824)
   #4 0x00007ff6496c701b (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1701b)
   #5 0x00007ff649cfd1d1 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x64d1d1)
   #6 0x00007ff649d046f3 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6546f3)
   #7 0x00007ff649d048b6 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6548b6)
   #8 0x00007ff64ac10e8a (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1560e8a)
   #9 0x00007ff649d9a8c2 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6ea8c2)
   #10 0x00007ff6498b303b (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x20303b)
   #11 0x00007ff6498b3383 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x203383)
   #12 0x00007ff6498b39d5 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x2039d5)
   #13 0x00007ff64a6ad5ff (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0xffd5ff)
   #14 0x00007ff64a9c82e2 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x13182e2)
   #15 0x00007ff64b8f13f3 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x22413f3)
   #16 0x00007ff64a934a60 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1284a60)
   #17 0x00007ff649c6eb7f (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x5beb7f)
   #18 0x00007ff649cba8f6 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x60a8f6)
   #19 0x00007ff6496b6576 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6576)
   #20 0x00007ff6496b43fa (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x43fa)
   #21 0x00007ff6496b1395 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1395)
   #22 0x00007ff6496b14c8 (D:\software\Android\SDK\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x14c8)
   #23 0x00007ffc402b7034 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x17034)
   #24 0x00007ffc410a2651 (C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x52651)
   clang++: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
   Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
   Target: armv7a-unknown-linux-android22
   Thread model: posix
   InstalledDir: D:/software/Android/SDK/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin
   clang++: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
   clang++: note: diagnostic msg:

---

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\Z00430~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Assembly-CSharp-f3eb5e.cpp
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\Z00430~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Assembly-CSharp-f3eb5e.sh
clang++: note: diagnostic msg:

---

at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions)
Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 434 successful nodes and 1 failed ones

> Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask FAILED

Answer (score 2):

Apparentely the problem is caused for IL2CPP and Script Debugging. Deactivate it and everythign will works well. For another hand, if you need debugging something, use MONO.

Comment: I found a new solution. It is easier than the last answer and you can use it with IL2CPP. Go to Player Settings, Other Settings and then C++ Compiler Configuration select Debug option.

Comment: Nice, this works. In my case I had to set _Faster (smaller) builds_ in Player Settings / Configuration / _IL2CPP Code Generation_. According to [Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/im-able-to-build-both-production-and-development-but-not-script-debugging-on.1187170/#post-8205018) this should be fixed in 2022.2

Comment: This is a life-saving answer, man!!! I got a slightly different error (saying something "Generics.cpp multiple definitions..."). Wall of error texts with paths. But switching to Mono helps.

Comment: @user3547063 You should add this as an answer. For me, this solved the problem.